# Are Decimal Values Considered True in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, floating-point, conditional-statements

I am currently writing a conditional statement that evaluates floating-point values.

```
float condition;
if(condition)
  // then do something
else
  // do something else
```

If condition is, say, 0.5 or 1/2, would the statement be considered True or False?
In other words, would the program execute the "then" or the "else" portion?

Comment: Try it in gcc  :)

Comment: '1/2' is not a float.

Comment: *Any* non-zero scalar value is "true", whether that scalar is a floating-point type, integral type, or pointer type.  A value of `0.0001` is true (or, perhaps more accurately, not false).

Comment: You can think of `if(condition)` as being the same as `if(condition != 0.0)`.  Note that if `condition` is the result of some computation, then this is probably not a very useful test, as values that should mathematically be exactly zero may not come out that way in finite-precision floating point.  In many cases you'd instead want something like `if (fabsf(condition) > SMALL_NUMBER)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the condition is equal to 0, it is considered false, otherwise it is considered true.

Section 6.8.4.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `if` statement states:

> *1* The controlling expression of an `if` statement shall have scalar type
>
> *2* In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0

Floating point types are considered scalar types, so they are valid as the expression of an `if`.

This also works for the values infinity and NaN, both of which compare unequal to 0.

Comment: A remark about -0.0, infinity, NaN would be useful.

Comment: See footnote 59 in C11 [§6.3.1.2 Boolean type](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.2): _59)  NaNs do not compare equal to 0 and thus convert to 1._

Comment: Sections [F.9.2 Expression transformations](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#F.9.2) and [F.9.3 Relational operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#F.9.3) in particular, and some of the earlier parts of Annex F, have relevant information about NaNs too, though it should be noted that Annex F is optional (but normative).